# FullPage.js touch scrolling over fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fixed, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js for my website. I have an fixed (horizontally and vertically centered) element above the fullpage-container, so when i swipe over that fixed part on my mobile device, fullpage doesn't recognise the touch event. Scrolling works fine.

The problem exists when the fixed div's are outside the fullpage container and even when they're inside. I'm using the 'fixedElements' Parmeter:

```
fixedElements: '.circleWrapper',
```

Should I bind the touch event somehow to the fullpage container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried `css3: false` on the fullpage.js configuration but didn't get it to work so I found the simple solution to just use

`pointer-events: none;`

on my element infront of the fullpage slides. This is the most simple solution i've found to solve my problem. For any questions about my implementation just ask!

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem. It seems you should be using the option `normalScrollElements` if what you want is to be able to scroll inside the fixed element.

Comment: No I just wanted the element to be fixed in front of the slides, the problem i had was that when I swiped over the fixed area the slides in the back didn't changed. The `normalScrollElements` option isn't a solution unfortunately.

Comment: I would test your solution in different browsers. Not quite sure that's a good solution for all browsers or devices.

Comment: I've tested it on android (chrome and firefox) and on ios (safari), it works on all these browsers. I'd be interested if it works on windows phone, but I'll test it someday I hope!

Answer (score 0):

fullpage.js touch events only work within the plugin's wrapper itself. 
Usually people do not want that swiping over headers or footers scrolls the page.

You have two options:

- Use `css3:false` and place your fixed elements within the fullpage.js container, so they will receive the swipe events and won't cause problems being inside the wrapper because the plugin won't be using translate3d properties.
- Modify fullpage.js to accomplish your own purposes. To do so, modify the functions `addTouchHandler` and `removeTouchHandler` and change `$(WRAPPER_SEL)` for `$(document)`:

  ```
  /**
  * Adds the possibility to auto scroll through sections on touch devices.
  */
  function addTouchHandler(){
      if(isTouchDevice || isTouch){
          //Microsoft pointers
          var MSPointer = getMSPointer();

          $(document).off('touchstart ' +  MSPointer.down).on('touchstart ' + MSPointer.down, touchStartHandler);
          $(document).off('touchmove ' + MSPointer.move).on('touchmove ' + MSPointer.move, touchMoveHandler);
      }
  }

  /**
  * Removes the auto scrolling for touch devices.
  */
  function removeTouchHandler(){
      if(isTouchDevice || isTouch){
          //Microsoft pointers
          var MSPointer = getMSPointer();

          $(document).off('touchstart ' + MSPointer.down);
          $(document).off('touchmove ' + MSPointer.move);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll try your first suggestion. Although the css-property `pointer-events: none;` on the element in front of the fullpage slider worked for me fine!